# Setting separate file permissions for Owner, Group, and All on the same folder

Tags: command-line, permissions, directory, chmod

How would I grant myself full file permissions on a particular folder, and also allow others to write to the folder (but not view its contents)?

I have already tried chown and chmod commands.

Comment: Tried what with chmod and chown?

Comment: What I mean is that I've tried using both chmod and chown to set file permissions to the desired effect.  However, another user has taught me to use the numeric format to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically use numeric format for establishing permissions. Here's a handy [calculator for converting](https://chmod-calculator.com/).

If you want other users to be able to deposit files in a directory without being able to view the contents of the target directory, you should set permissions as follows:

```
mkdir dropbox_dir
sudo chmod 733 dropbox_dir
```

So they would be able to write and execute but not read the dir.